# Add a MSBuild targets file to referencing projects

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj

I have a ClassLib1 project that is referenced by many other projects. I want to know if there is a way to include a build targets file for those referencing projects via the ClassLib1? Similar to the way a nugget package can.